# Точка появляется перед строкой с атрибутом round linecap в браузерах FF, IE

Tags: javascript, css3, svg, анимация, svg-animation

Я пытаюсь сделать простую анимацию рисования линии, используя SVG

Использую `javascript`, чтобы найти длину пути, а затем установить `stroke-dashoffset` и `stroke-dasharray`, поскольку формы являются динамическими.

Код показан ниже

```js
var path = document.querySelector("path");
path.style.strokeDasharray = path.getTotalLength();
path.style.strokeDashoffset = path.getTotalLength();
path.style.strokeLinecap = "round";
setTimeout(function(){
 path.style.transition = "stroke-dashoffset 1s"
 path.style.strokeDashoffset = 0;
},1000)
```

```html
<svg width="200" height="200">
    <path d="m10,10 h100 v100 h-100 v-100" stroke="black" fill="none" stroke-width="2"/>
</svg>
```

Вышеприведенный фрагмент отлично работает в `Chrome`. Но в `Firefox` и `Edge` точка появляется перед анимацией линии. Она появляется только в том случае, если указан параметр `stroke-linecap = round`. В противном случае анимация работает правильно.

Firefox:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Принимаются любые идеи, как удалить точку.

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Dot appears before line with round linecap FF,IE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53626733/7394871) от участника  [@Akshay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3971928/akshay).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/53626733/7394871

Comment: Это очень часто встречающийся баг  в Firefox, если применено свойство  **stroke-lineCap="round"** Поэтому будет полезно взять это решение на заметку

Answer (score 1):

Это, возможно, `bug`

Но это происходит из-за того, что ваше смещение штриха начинается точно там, где заканчивается черточка.

Таким образом, браузер считает, что перед запуском пробела есть тире нулевой длины. Круглые окончания добавляются в конец строки, даже если она имеет нулевую длину.

```
dash-array = 20 20
####################                    ####################
                   ^
                   dashoffset = 20
```

Простой способ обойти это состоит в том, чтобы сделать пробел `dash pattern`, шире, чем черта. Затем запустить анимацию в пробеле, а не прямо в начале ее.

```
dash-array = 20 21
####################                     ####################
                    ^
                    dashoffset = 20.5
```

И точка уходит.

```js
var path = document.querySelector("path");
path.style.strokeDasharray = [path.getTotalLength(), path.getTotalLength() + 1].join(' ');
path.style.strokeDashoffset = path.getTotalLength() + 0.5;
path.style.strokeLinecap = "round";
setTimeout(function(){
 path.style.transition = "stroke-dashoffset 1s"
 path.style.strokeDashoffset = 0;
},1000)
```

```css
path {
  stroke-width: 10;
}
```

```html
<svg width="200" height="200">
    <path d="m10,10 h100 v100 h-100 v-100" stroke="black" fill="none" stroke-width="2"/>
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [Dot appears before line with round linecap FF,IE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53627545/7394871) от участника  [@Paul LeBeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292848/paul-lebeau).</sub>

Comment: У меня FF 63 - всё ок.

Comment: @nick_n_a так ответ смотрите, здесь всё и должно быть ОК Смотрите сниппет в вопросе

Comment: @nick_n_a а выше гифки? сниппета у вас нет?

Comment: Да, в верхнем снипете есть точка.